# Repeatedly reasigning variable pointing to iterable

Tags: python, iterable

Consider the following code:

```py
import more_itertools as mo

def rep(x, n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield x

xs = [0]
for n in [1, 2, 3]:
    xs = mo.flatten(rep(x, n) for x in xs)

print(mo.ilen(xs))
```

The true answer should be 6, but it prints 27 why?

Note that `more_itertools.flatten` does the obvious thing and is actually an alias for `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. `more_itertools.ilen` also does the obvious thing and just counts the elements. I don't think that there are any bugs in the functions involved, just something about reasigning `xs`.

Comment: kaya3 is correct, if you want further proof, you can insert a line assigning `n` to something else just before `print(mo.ilen(xs))` and you'll see the result change accordingly (resulting in `n**3`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `mo.flatten(...)` calls are on generator expressions which are lazily evaluated, so the evaluation only occurs when the generator must be consumed on the final line by `mo.ilen(xs)`. At this point, the variable `n` has the value 3, so that's the value of `n` used when evaluating the generator expressions which [close](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) over `n`. (Note that although you might think `n` only exists within the loop, it is still in scope after the loop because Python does not have block scope.)

The result is that each of the three levels of nesting multiplies the length of the original sequence by 3, so that the final iterable has a length of 1×3×3×3 = 27 instead of 1×1×2×3 = 6. So this isn't really about `xs` being reassigned at all, it's about `n` being reassigned.

To get the expected behaviour (without eager evaluation), you can wrap the generator expression in a function call in order to close over a different `n` in each generator expression:

```py
import more_itertools as mo

def rep(x, n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield x

def make_flatten(xs, n):
    # here n is not reassigned in the local scope
    return mo.flatten(rep(x, n) for x in xs)

xs = [0]
for n in [1, 2, 3]:
    xs = make_flatten(xs, n)

print(mo.ilen(xs)) # prints 6, as expected
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Closing with `lambda` also works, so I'll probably go with that:
`xs = (lambda n: mo.flatten(rep(x, n) for x in xs))(n)`